# Spring AOP Cannot work for @Around

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-aop

I am currently working on AOP but some how the AOP cannot working, The @around is not invoking after and before the execution on specific controller.Folloeing is my code.

// my controller

```
package com.rest.controllers;
class ManCon{
@PostMapping(EndPointReferrer.UPDATE_DEALER_SCHEME_MAPPING_DETAILS)
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse> updateDealerSchemeMappingDetails(
            @RequestBody @NotNull @Valid Myclass obj){
    return null;  
   }

}
```

//configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.aop"})
public class AOPConfiguration {

    @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
    public SchemeMappingPortalAspect schemeMappingPortalAspect(){ return new SchemeMappingPortalAspect(); }

}
```

//Aspect

```
@Aspect
public class SchemeMappingPortalAspect {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchemeMappingPortalAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.rest.controllers.ManCon.updateDealerSchemeMappingDetails(..))")
    public void schemeMappingPointcut(){
    }

    /*
    * This is used for scheme mapping portal loging
    * */
    @Around(value = "schemeMappingPointcut()")
    public Object loggingSchemePortalDetail(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        logger.debug("-------------------------");
        logger.debug("In before calling");
        logger.debug("-------------------------");
        Object o=null;
        try {
            o= joinPoint.proceed();
            System.out.println("JSON::"+ new Gson().toJson(o));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.debug("-------------------------");
        logger.debug("In After Calling");
        logger.debug("-------------------------");
        return o;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you provide the advised method signature along with its class?

Comment: i added the controllers signature please see it

Comment: package names seem to be different on the class `com.softcell.rest.controllers` but `com.rest.controllers` on the Join Point.

Comment: which is correct in my application i change it in following did you find the other problem other than that

Comment: I dnt think the bean declaration for the aspect is required, as long as its within `com.aspect` it should be scanned and auto wired where needed. Can you remove that?

Comment: An `@Aspect` isn't an `@Component` so you need the `@Bean` definition. However you have created an additional `@Configuration` class are you sure that that class is detected by Spring Boot?

Comment: Maybe an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub incl. Maven build would others help to reproduce and solve your problem.